# Understanding inheritance in Google's V8 C++ code base

Tags: c++, inheritance, architecture, v8

I cannot understand the implementation of inheritance in Google's V8 JavaScript engine. It clearly (?) implements an inheritance hierarchy, but seems to completely do away with virtual functions.

This is the inheritance hierarchy as detailed in the [`objects.h` header file](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/master/src/objects.h):

```
// Inheritance hierarchy:
// - Object
//   - Smi          (immediate small integer)
//   - HeapObject   (superclass for everything allocated in the heap)
//     - JSReceiver  (suitable for property access)
//       - JSObject
//         - JSArray
// ... and many more entries
```

Most object types are derived from `Object`, which is declared as follows:

```
// Object is the abstract superclass for all classes in the
// object hierarchy.
// Object does not use any virtual functions to avoid the
// allocation of the C++ vtable.
// Since both Smi and HeapObject are subclasses of Object no
// data members can be present in Object.
class Object {
// ... bunch of method declarations and definitions
};
```

The relatively simple `Smi` class is declared next:

```
class Smi: public Object {
 public:
 // methods declarations and static member definitions
};
```

and so on.

For the life of me, I cannot understand how can, say, an instance of `Smi` can be used as an `Object`; there are *no virtual functions* and *I cannot find overrides in the [the implementation file, `objects.cc`](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/master/src/objects.cc)*. At 17,290 lines, though, trying to understand what is going on is proving a difficult task.

As another difficulty, I found an `ObjectVisitor` class in the same header file (this one is more *classical*; it consists of virtual methods). But I could not find the equivalent `Accept(Visitor*)` (or similar) method in the `Object` base class.

What I am asking in concrete is for a minimal example that illustrates how does this inheritance pattern works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classes in objects.h do not actually define real C++ classes. They do not have any fields. The classes are merely facades to objects managed on the V8 JavaScript heap. Hence they cannot have any virtual functions either, because that would require putting vtable pointers into the JS heap. Instead, all dispatch is done manually, via explicit type checks and down casts.

The `this` pointer inside methods isn't real either. For smis, `this` is simply an integer. For everything else it is a pointer into the V8 heap, off by one for tagging. Any actual accessor method masks this pointer and adds an offset to access the appropriate address in the heap. The offsets of each field is also defined manually in the classes.

Comment: This sounds very elaborate. Do you have any reference to another project that uses this approach?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `Object::IsPromise()` for a perfect example of how it works:

```
bool Object::IsPromise(Handle<Object> object) {
  if (!object->IsJSObject()) return false;
  auto js_object = Handle<JSObject>::cast(object);
  // Promises can't have access checks.
  if (js_object->map()->is_access_check_needed()) return false;
  auto isolate = js_object->GetIsolate();
  // TODO(dcarney): this should just be read from the symbol registry so as not
  // to be context dependent.
  auto key = isolate->promise_status();
  // Shouldn't be possible to throw here.
  return JSObject::HasRealNamedProperty(js_object, key).FromJust();
}
```

The way inheritance is used here is static. That is, type queries are done by a proxy or container (using some hidden magic, that, at a glance looks like they're using references to query a tag), and conversions from `Object` to a derived class is done by `static_cast<>()`. In that way, the member functions of the derived class can be called.

Note that in the above function, the type query and cast is indirectly performed by the `Handle<>` class, not by `Object` or any of its derived classes.

Note also that the functions which *accept* `ObjectVisitor` as a parameter are rather uniformly called `Iterate`, and that these functions all appear on proxies or handles.